# cgi get submitted image data-url

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cgi

Sorry if this question is dumb. I converted a jqplot image to data-url and send it with a form. In the new page, I used `cgi.FieldStorage()` to get the submitted data-url, but got nothing. So could anyone give me some suggestions on my approach? Thanks!

I am using Python on Google App Engine

Input page Javascript

```
var imgData = $('#chart1').jqplotToImageStr({});
$('<tr style="display:none"><td><input type="hidden" name="extract1"></td></tr>')
    .appendTo('.getpdf')
    .find('input')
    .data(imgData);
```

Output page:

```
def post(self):
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()   
    extract1 = form.getvalue('extract1') #extract1 is empty
```

I tried to print the form and it looked as:`MiniFieldStorage('extract1', '"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE`

If I assigned the data-url (data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...), it worked.

Comment: Are you sure that Javascript snippet is being called? Have you used developer mode in chrome to confirm that the `extract1` element exists?

Comment: Yes. Somehow it worked... but I have to use .val(imgData) instead. In the new page if I choose form.getvalue('extract1'), it is a PNG, and if I use str(form.getvalue('extract1')), it is still a jqplot object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have (working) code that does something similar.

```
def post(self):
  img_data = self.request.get('extract1')
  # then strip off the prefix and convert from base64
```

is what I'm doing. Poking into `cgi.FieldStorage` isn't something I normally see done in Python App Engine apps.